# What is a term for the use of two scripts in writing?

Tags: terminology, writing-systems

What is the best term to describe the following sentence?

> I live in 美国.

I've heard the term *macaronic* used to describe a mix of languages that use Roman script, but is there a more specific term for when a mix of orthographies from two distinct languages are used?  I've heard the term *mixed orthography* used to describe the Japanese writing system, but, of course, it is only one language; is the term appropriate for my example?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaronic_language), "Macaronic language" is a mish-mash of *words* from different languages, rather than the [mixed orthography](http://deu.proz.com/forum/sdl_trados_support/70512-failure_to_recognize_japanese_terms_with_mixed_orthography_mt7.html) of, say, Japanese.

Comment: If you live in 美国, surely you must speak 英語. All the Beautiful People do.

Comment: I support migration to Linguistics. Good luck there.

Comment: I'm not aware of a specific term but I guess you could call it code-switching, though that term usually refers to combining elements from different languages in speaking or signing, not in writing.

Answer (score 1):

There can be some confusion when we ask about how to describe a "sentence", and then discuss properties of how the sentence is written down.  We should distinguish *language* from *writing* ; they are distinct things, with independent properties.  Writing is (basically) a representation of language.

---

Let's think of  the language first.  The key question is, what linguistic utterance is that piece of writing *representing*?

- If it's representing "I live in Měiguó" (or "I live in Mei⁵gwok³", etc.), then the sentence displays [code-switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_switching), or [borrowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword).

  - *Macaronic* is a somewhat more informal term for frequent code-switching, sometimes mixing parts of words.  I wouldn't say this sentence looks particularly macaronic, though it could be part of a larger macaronic rant.
- If it's representing "I live in America"—that is, if the characters ‹美国› are supposed to be read as "America", the way e.g. Japanese read ‹大人› as *otona*—then there's no code-switching or borrowing going on.  It's just an everyday English sentence.

---

Now we turn to writing.  ‹I live in 美国› is a mixture of two writing systems.  I believe "mixed orthography" or "mixed writing" are reasonable labels for this phenomenon.  This is independent of how many languages are being represented; for example, ‹I live in Америкa› is mixed writing representing a pure English sentence.

Comment: "Digraphia" is also a word used for a mixture of two writing systems, especially when it's systematic.